# Add Directory based on CONDITION in WIX

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.8

Am learning WIX. I have got a question, I have 3 directories which internally have many files. I want to add these folders Folder 1,Folder 2,Folder 3 based on condition. I tried to have a condition inside Directory which is not working. I tried to give directory inside component which is also not working. How can i add directory based on condition.

```
<Directory Id="*" Name="bin">
<Condition>----------------------> Showing error

<Directory Id="*" Name="bin">
<component>
<Condition></condition>
<Directory id="">---------------------->This is showing error
</component>
</Directory>
```

Coming to files i harvested them into single file .wxs and am trying to add that file inside directories.

```
heat dir <mydir> Folder1.wxs -srag -gg -cg folderGroupId -dr BIN_FOLDER1 --> Creating FOLDER1.wxs successfully
```

with "folderGroupId" and "BIN_FOLDER1" directory id

Help me in this . Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to build multiple different MSI files that each install their own preselected subset of your files, or are you trying to make one MSI that enables someone to install each of those subsets based on a selection made at installation time?

Comment: Am thinking of selected at installation time and one folder should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend grouping all the relevant components and directories into a Feature (which doesn't need to be visible to the user) and having a Feature condition.

Comment: Am done the same now am getting error as unresolved reference to componentgroupID. I taught it might not be compiling so am trying to do candle.exe now it showing different error as preprocessor variable undefines